# Trying to use IIF as ternary operator/without evaluating both sides

Tags: excel, vba

I need to use `iif()` for my case of checking and assigning values like:

```
Range("A1").Value = IIf(IsNull(Range("A2").Value), MsgBox("1"), MsgBox("2"))
```

I'm really confused with this: the line is executing both `MsgBox`es. I need to execute only one of them depending on whether the condition is true/false.

I tried using `if` condition, but it causes an error: "Compile error: Expected: expression"

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The [VBA documentation for IIf](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) states that it executes both True and False conditions regardless of its output.

You need code similar to the following:

```
Dim Result as Integer
If IsNull(Range("A2").Value) Then
    Result = MsgBox("1")
Else
    Result = MsgBox("2")
End If
Range("A1").Value = Result
```

Alternatively, if you're looking for an one-liner:

```
Range("A1").Value = MsgBox(IIf(IsNull(Range("A2").Value), "1", "2"))
```

Though this doesn't allow you to change the other `MsgBox` parameters as easily as the block-If.

Comment: The VBA documentation for `IIf` is wrong. **Every single function ever invoked** in VBA needs to have its arguments evaluated before the function receives their result as a parameter value. `IIf` isn't to blame here, this is basic language mechanics. Also that link is for the MS-Access `IIf` function, which unless I'm mistaken is part of Access-SQL, not VBA.